# Bar chart created using highcharts on a VF page is not coming on a pdf when renderas = "pdf"

Tags: jquery, highcharts, salesforce, visualforce

I had created a vf page having a stacked bar chart usign highcharts API's.

```
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: '{!ReportName}'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: {!stackGroupings},
        labels: {
            style: {whitespace:'normal'},
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: '{!$Label.AnnualContractValue} ({!UserCurrency})'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} K'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                align: 'left',
                color: 'red',
                enabled: true
            }
        },    
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        // used for redirecting to the Drill Down Report
                        viewDrillDown();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    }
});
```

But when i render this page as a PDF , this bar chart is not showing. So is it possible to have a bar chart on a pdf when renderas="pdf" and if it is possible, does someone have a solution for this?

Comment: Could you recreate your excample as live demo ?

Comment: I would guess it's caused by animation in Highcharts, have you tried to disable all possible animations in a chart? Also, check if VF is rendering SVG to PDF - Highcharts are using SVG to render charts.